# RethinkDB - Free clients

Tags: rethinkdb

I tried RethinkDB Adminstration Console to run some queries but it doesn't work fine as the queries get stuck. On the other hand, the ReQLs execute fine from my code.

I am looking for a client where I can experiment my queries before doing actual coding.

Are there any free RethinkDB UI clients available?

Answer (score 3):

One option you can try is using the RethinkDB Python driver in an interactive shell.

Once you install it through `sudo pip install rethinkdb` (assuming you're on Linux), you can launch it by running `python -m rethinkdb repl`.

Note that the Python syntax for ReQL commands is slightly different from the JavaScript syntax. If you prefer JavaScript syntax, there are other tools available that you could try:

Node.js ReQL repl: https://www.npmjs.com/package/recli

These might also be interesting for you:

ReQLPro (a data browser): http://utils.codehangar.io/rethink

https://github.com/athlite/rethinkdb-cli